# Dynamically defining instance fields in Python classes

Tags: python

I am new to Python having come from mainly Java programming.

I am currently pondering over how classes in Python are instantiated.

I understand that `__init__()`: is like the constructor in Java. However, sometimes python classes do not have an `__init__()` method which in this case I assume there is a default constructor just like in Java?

Another thing that makes the transition from Java to python slightly difficult is that in Java you have to define all the instance fields of the class with the type and sometimes an initial value. In python all of this just seems to disappear and developers can just define new fields on the fly.

For example I have come across a program like so:

```
class A(Command.UICommand):
    FIELDS = [
        Field( 'runTimeStepSummary', BOOL_TYPE)
        ]

    def __init__(self, runTimeStepSummary=False):
        self.runTimeStepSummary = runTimeStepSummary

    """Other methods"""

    def execute(self, cont, result):
        self.timeStepSummaries = {}
        """ other code"""
```

The thing that confuses (and slightly irritates me) is that this A class does not have a field called timeStepSummaries yet how can a developer in the middle of a method just define a new field? or is my understanding incorrect?

So to be clear, my question is in Python can we dynamically define new fields to a class during runtime like in this example or is this timeStepSummaries variable an instance of a java like private variable?

EDIT: I am using python 2.7

Comment: Presumably the methods that appear to be missing are defined on the parent class. And pythons scoping rules are vastly different from Java's. Anyone can just declare a new variable or field and it will be created (in most cases). This is all stuff that's pretty basic to python so I would definitely recommend reading a book about it. Personally I used "dive in to python." Just Google around for python introductions. Good luck!

Comment: @scott_fakename: Thank you for the book reference.

Comment: classes work rather differently in python 2 vs 3 so you should specify which we're talking about here.

Comment: @roippi: I am using python 2.7. This is now added in my original question above.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> I understand that `__init__()`: is like the constructor in Java.

To be more precise, in Python `__new__` is the constructor method, `__init__` is the initializer. When you do `SomeClass('foo', bar='baz')`, the `type.__call__` method basically does:

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = cls.__new__(*args, **kwargs)
    instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return instance
```

Generally, most classes will define an `__init__` if necessary, while `__new__` is more commonly used for immutable objects.

> However, sometimes python classes do not have an **init**() method which in this case I assume there is a default constructor just like in Java?

I'm not sure about old-style classes, but this is the case for new-style ones:

```
>>>> object.__init__
<slot wrapper '__init__' of 'object' objects>
```

If no explicit `__init__` is defined, the default will be called.

> So to be clear, my question is in Python can we dynamically define new fields to a class during runtime like in this example

Yes.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.one_attribute = 'one'
...     def add_attr(self):
...         self.new_attribute = 'new'
...

>>> a = A()
>>> a.one_attribute
'one'
>>> a.new_attribute
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'new_attribute'
>>> a.add_attr()
>>> a.new_attribute
'new'
```

Attributes can be added to an instance at any time:

```
>>> a.third_attribute = 'three'
>>> a.third_attribute
'three'
```

However, it's possible to restrict the instance attributes that can be added through the class attribute `__slots__`:

```
>>> class B(object):
...     __slots__ = ['only_one_attribute']
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.only_one_attribute = 'one'
...     def add_attr(self):
...         self.another_attribute = 'two'
...

>>> b = B()
>>> b.add_attr()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in add_attr
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'another_attribute'
```

(It's probably important to note that `__slots__` is primarily intended as a *memory optimization* - by not requiring an object have a dictionary for storing attributes - rather than as a form of run-time modification prevention.)

Answer (score 7):

Attributes of Python objects are generally stored in a dictionary, just like the ones you create with `{}`. Since you can add new items to a dictionary at any time, you can add attributes to an object at any time. And since any type of object can be stored in a dictionary without previous declaration of type, any type of object can be stored as an attribute of an object.

In short,  `my_object.abc = 42` is (often) just a shorthand for `my_object.__dict__["abc"] = 42`.

It is possible to define objects without a `__dict__` by defining the `__slots__` attribute, or to override certain special methods and store attributes in some other way, though most of the time you shouldn't do that.

Comment: It isn't really true that setting an attribute is "just a shorthand" for modifying the dict. Data descriptors take precedence over instance attributes, which requires a full search of the `__mro__` before it can move on to the instance dict (if present). Also, the dict of a class is wrapped by a proxy that prevents direct modification, so the statement is untrue of objects in general.

Comment: You are technically correct... the best kind of correct. I'll cop to oversimplifying for the sake of a newbie.

Comment: I figured that's what you were doing, since I'm sure you know Python very well. I'm just OCD enough to think it needs the footnote.

Answer (score 0):

This answer pertains to new-style Python classes, which subclass `object`. New-style classes were added in 2.2, and they're the only kind of class available in PY3.

```
>>> print object.__doc__
The most base type
```

The class itself is an instance of a metaclass, which is usually `type`:

```
>>> print type.__doc__
type(object) -> the object's type
type(name, bases, dict) -> a new type
```

Per the above docstring, you can instantiate the metaclass directly to create a class:

```
>>> Test = type('Test', (object,), {'__doc__': 'Test class'})
>>> isinstance(Test, type)
True
>>> issubclass(Test, object)
True
>>> print Test.__doc__
Test class
```

Calling a class is handled by the metaclass `__call__` method, e.g. `type.__call__`. This in turn calls the class `__new__` constructor (typically inherited) with the call arguments in order to create an instance. Then it calls `__init__`, which may set instance attributes.

Most objects have a `__dict__` that allows setting and deleting attributes dynamically, such as `self.value = 10` or `del self.value`. It's generally bad form to modify an object's `__dict__` directly, and actually disallowed for a class (i.e. a class dict is wrapped to disable direct modification). If you need to access an attribute dynamically, use the [built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) `getattr`, `setattr`, and `delattr`.

The data model defines the following special methods for [customizing attribute access](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access): `__getattribute__`, `__getattr__`, `__setattr__`, and `__delattr__`. A class can also define the descriptor protocol methods `__get__`, `__set__`, and `__delete__` to determine how its instances behave as attributes. Refer to the [descriptor guide](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).

When looking up an attribute, `object.__getattribute__` first searches the object's class and base classes using the [C3 method resolution order](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) of the class:

```
>>> Test.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Test'>, <type 'object'>)
```

Note that a data descriptor defined in the class (e.g. a `property` or a `member` for a slot) takes precedence over the instance dict. On the other hand, a non-data descriptor (e.g. a function) or a non-descriptor class attribute can be shadowed by an instance attribute. For example:

```
>>> Test.x = property(lambda self: 10)
>>> inspect.isdatadescriptor(Test.x)
True
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.x
10
>>> t.__dict__['x'] = 0
>>> t.__dict__
{'x': 0}
>>> t.x
10

>>> Test.y = 'class string'
>>> inspect.isdatadescriptor(Test.y)
False
>>> t.y = 'instance string'
>>> t.y
'instance string'
```

Use [`super`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) to proxy attribute access for the next class in the method resolution order. For example:

```
>>> class Test2(Test):
...     x = property(lambda self: 20)
... 
>>> t2 = Test2()
>>> t2.x
20
>>> super(Test2, t2).x
10
```