# Why does the attribute get set but does not persist

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to dynamically add an attribute to at runtime using the following snippets of code:

## View

```
...
for appellation in queryset:
  if appellation.id in used_id_set:
    appellation.is_used_flag()
    print(appellation.is_used)
    # prints true as expected
  else:
    appellation.is_not_used_flag()

  first = queryset.first()
  print(first.is_used)
  # prints AttributeError: 'Appellation' object has no attribute 'is_used'
```

## In Model

```
...
def is_used_flag(self):
  self.is_used = True
def is_not_used_flag(self):
  self.is_used = False
```

Why does it work correctly when in the loop but when I try to retrieve the attribute from an instance after it does not work? I have run into the same issue using setattr, `appellation.is_used = True` and modifying `__dict__`. Also is there a better way to do this?

I have referenced these posts:
[Why can't you add attributes to object in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285269/why-cant-you-add-attributes-to-object-in-python) I do have a dict but it does not seem to "persist" after the loop

[How to assign a new class attribute via __dict__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432786/how-to-assign-a-new-class-attribute-via-dict) Same issue as mentioned above

[Dynamically defining instance fields in Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517740/dynamically-defining-instance-fields-in-python-classes) Same as above

## Update

Since both answers mention similar things, I should clarify what my intentions are. I do not want to actually persist the value in the DB. I just want to serialize it and use it in the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Queryset API in django (often) returns other querysets, which are in turn evaluated by accessing the database. By doing `queryset.first()` you're executing another database call, where your attributes have not been yet set.

If you need to save this `is_used` flag between querysets (*persist* the change), I suggest you add a BooleanField on your model, or perhaps find another way to do what you want, as in memory attributes will not get returned by using the queryset API.

Comment: The problem was first() making the extra call. Learned something new thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want the change to persist you will need to call `self.save()` after setting `is_used`, assuming that `is_used` is a field on the `Appellation` model.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Appellation(models.Model):
    # ... rest of code ...

    is_used = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def is_used_flag(self):
        self.is_used = True
        self.save()

    def is_not_used_flag(self):
        self.is_used = False
        self.save()
```

Note that Django instances are still Python objects so adding an attribute dynamically will work in the same way, this is why it prints `True` as expected in the code you provided.